# Creating a formula from a data frame using non-numeric arguments in R

Tags: r, variables, formula, apply

I'm trying to create a formula from a list of variables in a dataframe that I will eventually feed into a ODE solver from the following data:

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+
| React1 | React2 | React3 |  Prod1  | Prod2 | Prod3 |    k     |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+
| $OH    | $OH    | NA     | H2O2    | NA    | NA    | 5.50E+09 |
| $OH    | $HO2   | NA     | H2O     | O2    | NA    | 7.10E+09 |
| $OH    | $O2    | NA     | OH      | O2    | NA    | 1.00E+10 |
| H2O2   | $OH    | NA     | $HO2    | H2O   | NA    | 2.70E+07 |
| $OH    | HCO3   | NA     | $CO3    | NA    | NA    | 8.50E+06 |
| $OH    | CO2    | NA     | $CO3    | NA    | NA    | 1.00E+06 |
| $OH    | CO3    | NA     | $CO3    | OH    | NA    | 3.90E+08 |
| $OH    | $CO3   | NA     | unknown | NA    | NA    | 3.00E+09 |
| Cl     | $OH    | NA     | $ClOH   | NA    | NA    | 4.30E+09 |
| $Cl2   | $OH    | NA     | HOCl    | Cl    | NA    | 1.00E+09 |
| HOCl   | $OH    | NA     | $ClO    | H2O   | NA    | 2.00E+09 |
| ClO    | $OH    | NA     | $ClO    | OH    | NA    | 8.80E+00 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+
```

The goal is to get an equation from this data frame which multiplies React1, React2, React3, and k from each column together and then sum that entire column together (analagous to SUMPRODUCT in excel). For example:

Denominator Sum = 5.5E9*$OH*$OH + 7.1E9*$OH*$HO2 + ... 8.8E0*CLO*$OH

I have tried the following code which doesn't work as I am trying to apply a binary operator to non-numeric arguments.

```
Reactants <- Reactants %>% mutate(
  Sum = apply( Reactants, MARGIN = 1, Multiplication(React1,React2,React3,k), na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

My question is what is the best way to go about this? I have a feeling that I might be able to accomplish this using the `as.formula` and `paste` functions, but I am running into difficulty here as well. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Moreover, I will have to concatenate/ combine this function with a similar equation for the products, and incirporate all this in a for loop.

Comment: Are we supposed to be assuming that the "cells" all have numeric values? Putting "$OH" and then having a product that was also a character value made me think that you wanted some sort of symbolic manipulation.

Comment: Hey 42, all the cells are supposed to be non-numeric variables that I will perform binary operations on to make a formula.

Answer (score 2):

Using `DF` defined in the Note at the end, use `apply` with the indicated function and then paste together its elements.

```
nms <- grep("^React|^k$", names(DF), value = TRUE)
Prod <- function(x) paste(sub("^(\\$.*)$", "`\\1`", na.omit(x)), collapse = "*")
paste(apply(DF[nms], 1, Prod), collapse = " + ")
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "React1 | React2 | React3 |  Prod1  | Prod2 | Prod3 |    k

 $OH    | $OH    | NA     | H2O2    | NA    | NA    | 5.50E+09
 $OH    | $HO2   | NA     | H2O     | O2    | NA    | 7.10E+09
 $OH    | $O2    | NA     | OH      | O2    | NA    | 1.00E+10
 H2O2   | $OH    | NA     | $HO2    | H2O   | NA    | 2.70E+07
 $OH    | HCO3   | NA     | $CO3    | NA    | NA    | 8.50E+06
 $OH    | CO2    | NA     | $CO3    | NA    | NA    | 1.00E+06
 $OH    | CO3    | NA     | $CO3    | OH    | NA    | 3.90E+08
 $OH    | $CO3   | NA     | unknown | NA    | NA    | 3.00E+09
 Cl     | $OH    | NA     | $ClOH   | NA    | NA    | 4.30E+09
 $Cl2   | $OH    | NA     | HOCl    | Cl    | NA    | 1.00E+09
 HOCl   | $OH    | NA     | $ClO    | H2O   | NA    | 2.00E+09
 ClO    | $OH    | NA     | $ClO    | OH    | NA    | 8.80E+00"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE,
 as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: hey,I am trying to post a question, in dput function Lable=c( is very large for 4 rows and 4 column. do you know what is problem and how I can fix it? –

Comment: I meant dput function

Comment: structure(list(SAMPN = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 28L), .Label = c("    4", 
"    8", "    9", "   19", "   21", "   26", "   27", "   40", 
"   47", "   51", "   53", "   60", "   64", "   69", "   73", 
"   74", "   78", "   82", "   83", "   84", "   87", "   89", 
"   92", "   94", "   96", "   98", "  100", "  102", "  104", 
"  106", "  115""  118", "  119", "  120", "  127", "  129", 
"  135", "  138", "  139", "  140", "  141", "  142", "  144", 
"  145", "  149", "  ....

Comment: I know but Lable is very large, I don't know what is that. I can't paste it.

Comment: You can use `dput(head(DF))` or `dput(head(DF, k))` where `k` is the number of rows to use.

Comment: @hghg, If you have the answer now, I suggest you delete your comments so as not to hijack the comments that should all pertain to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Very smart approach to the problem so we can use the prod function.I had a follow up question. If converting the string to a formula, we would run into errors with "$" being part of a potential variable such as "$OH", correct? Would there be a way to circumvent this with an `expression` , or `regex` in stringi?

Comment: Have modified code to put backticks around names that start with $.

Comment: So if I am understading this correctly"  `^\\$` - match $ at start of string, `.*` - any character 0 or more times with `$` (i think?), and then capture the group with a reference symbol with `\\1`

Comment: Yes. It matches start of string, $ sign, any number of characters and puts it all in a capture group which is replaced with that group surrounded by backticks.  If the string does not start with $ sign then there is no match and it is left as is.

Comment: Thank you. One thing I have been struggling with is having the `sub` function ignore decimals and scientific notation. For example i ave a 0.126 and 1E-3 that are now being attached to backticks. Can I avoid these with a lookahead in conjuction with  `paste(sub("^(.*[[:punct:]].*)", "`\\1`"`